# regex for passwords 2numbers, 1capital, 4lowercase

Tags: regex

Im looking for a regex that checks for:

`a minimum of 2 numbers` and

`a minimum of 1 capital letter` and

`a minimum of 4 lowercase letters`

And also checks for:

`a maximum of 30 characters`

I've been trying to make this but all my creations don't work :)
You can leave the maximum out too if you can't do it, I could check it in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{7,30}$
```

But if you want only the alphanumerics, then:

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,30}$
```

`(?=.*\d.*\d)`: at least two digits

`(?=.*[A-Z])`: one caps letter

`(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])`: minimum four lowercase

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,30}`: length between 7-30

Comment: Thanks, it works like a beast!

Only I changed `{7,30}` to `{6,30}` since the 4 lowercase letters may also be 3 lowercase letters and 1 uppercase ;)

Comment: No problem, either way it will do! :-)

Comment: Can you please explain how it works and in particular what `?=` does? I am reading `man perlre` but I cannot put it together yet.

Comment: `(?=.*[A-Z])` means it check to see whether there is any Capital letter in front. Similar for the other `(?=)`. It says Look-Ahead in regex.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the order of those conditions is arbitrary. Therefore there is no need to do it using just 1 regexp. For each condition, you can have 1 regexp and then you can do a logical conjunction in your favorite language and it would be much more readable than one super-cool-ninja-regexp.

- a minimum of 2 numbers

`".*\d.*\d.*"`

- a minimum of 1 capital letter and

`".*[A-Z].*"`

- a minimum of 4 lowercase letters

`".*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]"`

- a maximum of 30 characters

`".{6,30}"`